# Select text on click for multiple textbox with random IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple textboxes on my page, their ID starts with 'Text' and followed by a random string like this 'Textc0816e05-d7c0-4acc-b233-bef152781cac', How can I have the textbox' value selected when user click on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type=text][id^=Text]').on('click', function() {
   console.log(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the clicked textbox value with following code

```
$('input[type=text][id^=Text]').on('click',function(){
     var value = $(this).val();

     //do what ever you want with the values
});
```

You can check the [`Attributes start with selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) doc.